# What will be performance impact if I will drop all statistics from my database in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, sql-server-2014

I have a website which is running since last 7 years, for back end database we were using Sql Server 2008 and recently we have migrated on Sql Server 2014.

Now a days, we are facing issues like slowness suddenly with some of pages only.
I want to know that whether this due to Statistic on tables, which are used in slow pages. As per [SQL Server: Auto Statistics Cleanup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2013/09/09/sql-server-auto-statistics-cleanup/) blog post, it is recommended to drop all the existing statistics as our database gradually do so many CRUD operations and changes in table definitions as well.

Please note that I have set Auto update statistics to ON.

So What should I do whether I have to drop all the statistics or not? if yes, what would be performance impact on my current web application? Is there any another way to identify slowness issue, which do come gradually with no deadlock or blocking conditions?

Comment: If you don't even know if statistics are your problem, dropping them all is not something you should start off with. If you moved from 2008 to 2014, you're also dealing with a brand new optimizer that makes different estimates even when faced with the same data. Analyze the slowness the usual way: identify the actual slow queries and study their query plans.

Comment: I used to do that thing since last few months and had improved till some extent and still we are doing that as well, but sometime I have noticed that only rebuild or reorganise of Indexes improves the performance, so reading different blogs, I came to know that unused or old/deprecated Statistics could be one of the reason as optimizer could not get correct or updated Statistics.

Comment: Keeping statistics up to date is important, and a good thing to schedule -- getting rid of unused statistics less so, unless you already know it's `INSERT` performance that's slow on your database (or the scheduled statistics updates take too much time). Certainly, do not schedule periodically dropping all statistics, that will cause unnecessary slowdowns. You can try a solution like [Ola Hallengren's scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) (disclaimer: no personal experience, but they're popular) or a simple `sp_updatestats`.

Answer (score 0):

This query gets all unused indexes and statistics. In order to optimize your DB you need to profile and tune the DB:

```
SELECT
    objects.name AS Table_name,
    indexes.name AS Index_name,
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_seeks,
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_scans,
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates
FROM
    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
    INNER JOIN sys.objects ON dm_db_index_usage_stats.OBJECT_ID = objects.OBJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes ON indexes.index_id = dm_db_index_usage_stats.index_id AND dm_db_index_usage_stats.OBJECT_ID = indexes.OBJECT_ID
WHERE
    indexes.is_primary_key = 0 --This line excludes primary key constarint
    AND
    indexes. is_unique = 0 --This line excludes unique key constarint
    AND 
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates <> 0 -- This line excludes indexes SQL Server hasn’t done any work with
    AND
    dm_db_index_usage_stats. user_lookups = 0
    AND
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_seeks = 0
    AND
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_scans = 0
ORDER BY
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_updates DESC
```